# GCP hive and dataflow without shuffle

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hive, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a Google Cloud Platform composer job with two parts - a hive (dataproc) query that generates a very large table, and a dataflow job that reads the parquet files backing that table, collects them using the first field (a user id, where every user has a few 100 rows), and then computes something using all the rows for the user.

What I am seeing is that the dataflow job has a sawtooth pattern of throughput, and my impression is that the shuffle step (I'm using Combine.perKey()) is causing this slowdown.

I'd like to be able to specify in the hive query that (1) the table has a specific number of files backing it, and (2) the space of user ids should be partitioned into those files.  Then, each worker in the dataflow job could process a single file (or multiple files), and not have to communicate with other workers via shuffle.

I'm a beginner with this technology so I'm wondering if this seems like the right way to fix throughput, and how it could be done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your Hive table clustered? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables. Thats easily gets you to map-side joins in Hive. Spark though... still a little behind https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19256